# PHP - forward a page on best way!

Tags: php, forward

**Possible Duplicate: [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431)**

---

Hi!
How do i forward a page on the best way? Should I use the header-funct. or should i use HTML (meta-tags) to refresh? I hope some experts could give me some advice at this point. Thanks!

Btw, the forwarding is made inside an if-statement if that could be to some problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to redirect the user to an URL, you can use the [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to send a `Location` HTTP header :

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/new-url.php');
die;
```

*(In theory, you should use an absolute URL that includes the domain name -- but most browsers accept a non-absolute URL)*

You can use this wherever you want in your script, even inside a `if`-block, of course.

The only thing is, as you are setting an HTTP-header : you must not have sent any kind of output before *(not even a white space at the end of an included file)*.

Comment: Okay, thanks! So I could do this to add variable to URL:

header('Location: http://www.example.com/new-url.php?ref='. $ref .'');

Comment: Also be careful when you pass variables, one bad example: header('Location: example.com/$_GET["url"].php')

Comment: Yes, you can add variables to the URL : you just have to build the URL you want to redirect to ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript.

```
echo "<script>location.replace(\"$url\");</script>";
```

Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp .